# How to get embedded variables in template in Go language

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree, go-templates

I'd like to get all embedded variables in a template in Go language.

For example, in a template, `template.New("test").Parse("{{.Count}} items are made of {{.Material}}")`, `".Count"` and `".Material"` are variables. I tried to find ways to get variables in document, source code and in web, but I could not find it.

Here is my expectation.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
)

func getVariables(t *template.Template) []string {
  // ... How to implement?
}

func main() {
    t, _ := template.New("test").Parse("{{.Count}} items are made of {{.Material}}")

    fmt.Println(getVariables(t))
    // My expectation is [.Count .Material]
}
```

Could you tell me how to get these variables?

Comment: Thank you very much icza! This is what I want. However, how about "{{range $i, $v := .arr}}{{$v}}{{end}}"? I'd like to get string[]{".arr"} but I could not get it by the provided source in the duplicate question.

Comment: Quoting from my answer there: _"This solution is just a demonstration, a proof of concept, it does not handle all cases."_ If you want to handle all cases, you have to "dig deeper" into into the AST. But also note: _"...the `Template.Tree` field is 'exported only for use by html/template and should be treated as unexported by all other clients.'"_ So you shouldn't rely on this either.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'll dig deeper and implement to achieve my goal on my own. Thank you very much for your perfect demonstration.